# How to add aws ec2 at rundeck?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rundeck

I added a new `aws-ec2` source at `rundeck` and also inserted a `rundeck-ec2` plugin at the libext folder. Everything is working but this new `aws-ec2` node is not showing show at `nodes`.

Any idea what is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I leave the steps to use the ec2-plugin with Rundeck, in this guide I used [Amazon Linux 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOO1m.jpg) as EC2 instance.

1. Download the plugin from [here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin/releases), and put the `.jar` [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG9gC.jpg) on Rundeck [libext](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installation) directory.
2. Check that the plugin is ready, go to the Gear icon (up to right) > Plugins > Installed Plugins, if you use the textbox to find "ec2" [you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7TQ7.jpg) that the plugin is well installed on your Rundeck instance.
3. Now it's time to add your nodes, go to Project Settings (Rundeck sidebar) > Edit Nodes and click on "Add a new Node Source +" [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MONdy.jpg). Then select "AWS EC2 Resources" from [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r40oo.jpg).

   So, you need to pass some parameters to connect to your EC2 nodes. Focus on the "Access Key", "Secret Key" and "Endpoint" textboxes.

   You can get the first and second one going to your AWS profile [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3A8E.jpg) (Up to right on AWS) > "My Security Credentials" > and click on "Create access key" [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fe6y.jpg), that [generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpFd8.jpg) the Access Key ID and Secret Key (also, you can use some Access Key ID/Secret access key created before).

   The third one ("Endpoint"), it's an HTTPS URL with your instance Endpoint, for example, if your EC2 nodes are in US East (N. Virginia) Zone, you need to put `https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`, you can see all endpoint codes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region).
4. If you click on "Nodes" (Rundeck sidebar) you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2chK2.jpg) your EC2 nodes listed.
5. Now, you need to access them, for that you have two methods.

   *5a. Using the AWS `.pem` [file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html):* Click on the Gear Icon (up to right) > [Key Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6C3U.jpg) and [add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd4IB.jpg) a new Private key with the `.pem` file content, give it a name, and save it. Now go to Edit Configuration (Rundeck Sidebar) > Default Node Executor tab and reference your Key Storage entry on "SSH key Storage Path" [textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c02wL.jpg), save it.

   *5b. Like any SSH remote node:* Just add the rundeck user (or the user that launches Rundeck) public key (`id_rsa.pub` file) content on the `autorized_keys` (`/home/ec2-user/.ssh/autorized_keys`), and now the EC2 node trusts the Rundeck instance.
6. Run any command against your [nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMM6o.jpg) on the Rundeck's [Commands](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/06-commands.html#commands) page.

You can see the full documentation [here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin#rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCeMR3T2uIE) a video about Rundeck and EC2 usage.